# Sticking CSS footer on bottom

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get this footer to stick on the bottom despite trying numerous methods I searched for.

Basically I have the header at the top with a box shadow separating it from the rest of the page and I want the same at the bottom, with the content in the middle, any ideas what I am doing wrong?  I have tried position fixed, bottom 0 but I can't get the box shadow to show using those methods or keep it centered.

Thanks!

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
div {
  display: block;
}
.header-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 940px;
}
.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}
#header {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 0 25px 0;
}
#header .logo {
  float: left;
}
#header .logo a {
  display: block;
  width: 270px;
  height: 60px;
  text-indent: -999em;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: url(/test/_assets/img/header-logo.png) no-repeat 0px 1px;
  background-size: 270px 60px;
}
#header .american-flag {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
#header .american-flag img {
  max-height: 60px;
}
#content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
body a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.footer-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#footer {
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="container" id="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="/">URL</a>
      </div>
      <div class="american-flag">
        FLAG
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="content">
    Site content
  </div>
  <div class="footer-wrapper">
    <div class="container" id="footer">
      footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You want the footer to be at the bottom, that will have the box-shadow and it's content is centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have applied [Ryan Fait's sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/) to your markup.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
div {
  display: block;
}
.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
}
.header-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 940px;
}
.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}
#header {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 0 25px 0;
}
#header .logo {
  float: left;
}
#header .logo a {
  display: block;
  width: 270px;
  height: 60px;
  text-indent: -999em;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: url(/test/_assets/img/header-logo.png) no-repeat 0px 1px;
  background-size: 270px 60px;
}
#header .american-flag {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
#header .american-flag img {
  max-height: 60px;
}
#content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
body a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.footer-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#footer {
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="container" id="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="/">URL</a>
      </div>
      <div class="american-flag">
        FLAG
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="content">
    Site content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer-wrapper">
  <div class="container" id="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, great job.

Answer (score 1):

check the following css

```
.footer-wrapper
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     bottom: 0px; /* add this line */
     position:fixed;  /* add this line */
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: That does stick it to the bottom thanks but it leaves the footer off-center

Comment: There's a couple fixes that will need to be applied to this answer. First, set `width: 100%;` to `.footer-wrapper`. Then you will need to set a bottom margin on `#content` equal to the height of the footer so content isn't hidden by the overlapping footer element due to fixed positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc()` function of CSS with `min-height` property.

Like:

```
#content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px); // Viewport Height (100%) - Remaining space of the content & header (135px)
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
html 
{
/*  overflow-y: scroll; */
}
body 
{
 margin:0;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 font-family:'Ubuntu',sans-serif;
}
div
{
 display:block;
}
.header-wrapper
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.container
{
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 width:940px;
}
.container:before, .container:after 
{
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "";
}
#header
{
 height:60px;
 padding:20px 0 25px 0;
}
#header .logo
{
 float:left;
}
#header .logo a
{
    display: block;
    width: 270px;
    height: 60px;
    text-indent: -999em;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: url('/test/_assets/img/header-logo.png') no-repeat 0px 1px;
 background-size: 270px 60px;
}
#header .american-flag
{
 display:block;
 float:right;
}
#header .american-flag img
{
 max-height:60px;
}
#content
{
 height:100%;
 padding:20px 0 0 0;
}
body a 
{ 
 color:red; 
 text-decoration:none; 
}
body a:hover 
{ 
 text-decoration: underline; 
}
.footer-wrapper
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#footer
{
 line-height:60px;
 height:60px;
}

#content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 185px);
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="container" id="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="/">URL</a>
        </div>
        <div class="american-flag">
         FLAG
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="content">
Site content
</div>
<div class="footer-wrapper">
 <div class="container" id="footer">
 footer
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There's a gap at the bottom between the viewport and footer bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to the `.footer-wrapper` class:

```
.footer-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action since it doesn't look as good in the code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/jm2rveqc/

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
div {
  display: block;
}
.header-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 940px;
}
.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}
#header {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 0 25px 0;
}
#header .logo {
  float: left;
}
#header .logo a {
  display: block;
  width: 270px;
  height: 60px;
  text-indent: -999em;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: url(/test/_assets/img/header-logo.png) no-repeat 0px 1px;
  background-size: 270px 60px;
}
#header .american-flag {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
#header .american-flag img {
  max-height: 60px;
}
#content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
body a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.footer-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#footer {
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="container" id="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="/">URL</a>
      </div>
      <div class="american-flag">
        FLAG
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="content">
    Site content
  </div>
  <div class="footer-wrapper">
    <div class="container" id="footer">
      footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A margin will need to be applied to the content element equal to the height of the footer so content isn't hidden by the overlapping footer element.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use **Flexbox** for those cases.

Simply change

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

to

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to your body

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

and finally add `margin-top: auto` to your footer wrapper

```
.footer-wrapper {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

is ithis not satisfying?

```
 #footer {
      line-height: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Perhaps an example with some content [where the user has to scroll](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOOWxb).

Comment: [That doesn't work either](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOOwJP). The footer doesn't stick to the bottom when there isn't enough content to fill the height of the viewport. The point of a sticky footer is to be at the bottom of the page regardless of the amount of content on the page.

Comment: That doesn't work either. At least the way you have implemented it.